# I need to pause my custom timer and start from last value using rxjs operators

Tags: reactjs, rxjs

I have next code. This is my custom timer, that start counting after click "start", reset to "0" seconds by click "reset" button. And now, i need to add "wait" button for pause counting.

```
const observable$ = interval(1000)
const actionReset$ = new Subject ();
const actionWait$ = new Subject ();


function customTimer () {
  const [ time, setTime] = useState (0);
  const [ timerOn, setTimerOn ] = useState (false);
  

useEffect(() => {  
  let subscription = actionReset$.pipe(
    startWith(null),
    switchMap(() => observable$),
  ).subscribe(result =>{
    if (timerOn) {
      setTime(result);
    } else {
      return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  });
  return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
}, [timerOn]);


return (
    <div className="mainBlock">
//....//
        {!timerOn && (
        <button onClick={() => setTimerOn(true)}>Start</button>
        )}
        { timerOn && (
        <button onClick={onStopClick}>Stop</button>
        )}
        { timerOn && (
        <button onClick={() => actionWait$.next('clickedwait')}>Wait</button>
        )}   
        { time > 0 && (
        <button onClick={() => actionReset$.next('clickedreset')}>Reset</button>
        )}   
      </div>  
);
}

export default customTimer;
```

So, i need to pause counting of my custom timer by click "wait" button and continue it from last value after click "start" button. I can`t find right operators for it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no pause operator.  There was a pausable concept in the past (see the [this reasoning for not implementing this operator](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/1542)), but this doesn't achieve what you are trying to do because you need to remember your own version of elapsed time.

There are different ways to achieve this, but here is one way using the scan operator.  This assumes the actionWait$ observable is a boolean observable.

```
const subscription = actionReset$.pipe(
    startWith(null),  // your code
    switchMap(() => observable$), // your code
    withLatestFrom(actionWait$),
    filter(([_, wait]) => !wait),  // ignore events while waiting
    scan((seconds, _) => ++seconds, 0),  // keep your own counter
);
```

Clearly this approach does not correctly manage parts of seconds during wait mode.